# How to delete an Item from Sqlite & List from Xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I got a big problem. I have got a list in Sqlite and I want to delete an item by menuitem clicked event. the code:

```
 async void MenuItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var nahrungsmittel = _nahrungsmittel[0];
            await _connection.DeleteAsync(nahrungsmittel);
            _nahrungsmittel.Remove(nahrungsmittel);

        }
```

For now its only deleting the first object in the observable collection and in db. how can I get delete the one I tapped on? There´s some more code if this should not be enough:

```
namespace EssenBestellen.Speisen
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class SpeisenUebersicht : ContentPage
    {

    private SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection;
    private ObservableCollection<Nahrungsmittel> _nahrungsmittel;

    public SpeisenUebersicht()
    {
        BindingContext = new 
EssenBestellen.ViewModels.NahrungsmittelListeViewModel(new 
EssenBestellen.ViewModels.PageService());
        InitializeComponent();

        _connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>().GetConnection();

    }

     async protected override void OnAppearing()
     {
         await _connection.CreateTableAsync<Nahrungsmittel>();

         var nahrungsmittel = await _connection.QueryAsync<Nahrungsmittel> 
("SELECT * FROM Nahrungsmittel ORDER BY NAME ASC"); //.ToListAsync();
         _nahrungsmittel = new ObservableCollection<Nahrungsmittel> 
  (nahrungsmittel);
        speisenListe.ItemsSource = _nahrungsmittel;


        base.OnAppearing();
    }

    async void Add_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new SpeisenAdd());
    }

    async void MenuItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var nahrungsmittel = _nahrungsmittel[0];
        await _connection.DeleteAsync(nahrungsmittel);
        _nahrungsmittel.Remove(nahrungsmittel);

    }


    private void speisenListe_ItemSelected(object sender, 
SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    (BindingContext as 






EssenBestellen.ViewModels.NahrungsmittelListeViewModel).SelectNahrungsmittel(e.S 



  electedItem as Nahrungsmittel);

    }

    private void MenuItem_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Kommt Noch","noch nicht implementiert", "OK");

    }


}
}
```

**Xaml file Update**

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<ToolbarItem Icon="plus.png" Text="Neu" Activated="Add_Clicked"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

<StackLayout>

<ListView x:Name="speisenListe" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Nahrungsmittels}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNahrungsmittel, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemTapped="speisenListe_ItemTapped" ItemSelected="speisenListe_ItemSelected">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <MenuItem Text="Bearbeiten" IsDestructive="False" Clicked="MenuItem_Clicked"  Command="{Binding .}" />
                    <MenuItem Text="Löschen" IsDestructive="True" Clicked="MenuItem_Clicked"  Command="{Binding .}" />
                </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Id}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Preis}" TextColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Are you using a listview? I would suggest you add the XAML code as well so we know what exactly have you done so far

Comment: sure, i will answer my questen and add it

Comment: Don't add it as an answer do it using the existing question as an edit see there is an option called edit next to share below the tags

Comment: sry 2 late. can you see it?

Comment: So you want to know which item in your listview was tapped right? And yeah you should delete your answer i updated it in the question itself

Comment: as you can see, there is this code: "var nahrungsmittel = _nahrungsmittel[0];". So the First object from the list will be deleted. but can i change the "[0]" into something like "selected item" or "the one i clicked at?"

Comment: Check my answer out below your listview gives you that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of me helped me, here´s the solution:

```
    async void MenuItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_nm != null)
        {
            await _connection.DeleteAsync(_nm);
            _nahrungsmittel.Remove(_nm);
        }

    }


    private void speisenListe_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.SelectedItem is Nahrungsmittel nm)
        {
            _nm = nm;
        }
    (BindingContext as EssenBestellen.ViewModels.NahrungsmittelListeViewModel).SelectNahrungsmittel(e.SelectedItem as Nahrungsmittel);

    }
```

there´s still a little mistake: you have to tap on the listItem for one time, after that you can hold/swipe & delete it. Same propblem with itemTapped, insted of Itemselected... but, all in all it s workig now

Answer (score 0):

Well in your ListView Itemtapped you have the following method where you can get the tapped item something like this:

```
 void speisenListe_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e) 
        {
           var clickedObj= e.Item as Nahrungsmittel;
           await _connection.DeleteAsync(clickedObj);
          _nahrungsmittel.Remove(clickedObj);

        };
```

Comment: hey, so i dont know any futher how to use this. just one example:
i want to do it like this:
var nahrungsmittel = _nahrungsmittel[>has du be int<]
var nahrungsmittel = _nahrungsmittel[NumberOfIndexOfTappedItem]
and i cant get it in there...

Comment: So you are getting your clicked item but you dont know how to use that object is it? I have edited my answer check it out

Comment: okay perfect, now i think we both know where the problem ist, thanks. there  still a little mistake: i made this "swipe to left(ios) or hold(droid)"-Menue item. So when i hold an item from the list, there apears a "löschen(=delete)"-button. now its like: tap on the item and its gone. but i want to do this with the "menueItem_clicked"-method. the problem: it doesnt know the "e.Item".. do you get what i mean?

Comment: i tried it like this:
 async void MenuItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var clickedObj = sender as Nahrungsmittel;
            await _connection.DeleteAsync(clickedObj);
            _nahrungsmittel.Remove(clickedObj);
        }
but there s n timeout exception, because i think it wants to know witch index oh the item it has to delete (like the "[0]")

Comment: In that case, see what type of object are you receiving in your events object you can do that using the watch

Comment: yeah right, exactly thats the problem, i dont know what i m receaving, or how i will implement this

Comment: Umm okay add a breakpoint on the first line of your method and check the e object what data is it getting with it